# Start appfuse project with tomcat7-maven-plugin stops in "Starting ProtocolHandler" step

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, tomcat7, appfuse

I am adding tomcat plugin in my **appfuse light** project pom file

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </plugin>
```

after executing this command

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

Everything is good before this step:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

But tomcat stops in this step for more than 10 minutes...

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: Does "mvn jetty:run" work?

Comment: Yes. "mvn jetty:run" works.

Comment: Which archetype did you use to create your project? I'll try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, for me it turned out not to be an actual problem. If you just type

```
http://localhost:8080
```

... then it just hangs forever. If you type

```
http://localhost:8080/<projectname>
```

... then the login scren will come up.